# How to get the AWS S3 bucket location via PHP api call?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I am searching on the internet on how can I get the AWS s3 bucket region with an API call or directly in PHP using their library but have not luck finding the info.

I have the following info available: 
Account credentials, bucket name, access key + secret. That is for multiple buckets, that I have access to, and I need to get the region programatically, so logging in to aws console and checking out is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an instance of the AWS PHP Client in `$client`, you should be able to find the location with `$client->getBucketLocation()`.

Here is some example code:

```
<?php

$result = $client->getBucketLocation([
    'Bucket' => 'yourBucket',
]);
```

The result will look like this

```
[
    'LocationConstraint' => 'the-region-of-your-bucket',
]
```

Comment: How can I instantiate AWS client? It requires the region it seems :/

Comment: You should be able to pick any of the regions, since the call to `getBucketLocation()` is bucket agnostic. You can find a list of available regions at [AWS Regions and Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region).

Answer (score 1):

When you create a S3 client, you can use any of the available regions in AWS, even if it's not one that you use.

```
$s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3MultiRegionClient([
            'version'     => 'latest',
            'region'      => 'us-east-1',
            'credentials' => [
                'key'    => $accessKey,
                'secret' => $secretKey,
            ],
        ]);

$region = $s3Client->determineBucketRegion($bucketname);
```